# Desktop Wallpaper Keeps Changing

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, desktop-background, system-settings

Using Trusty Tahr on Dell Inspiron 64 bit. I installed desktopnova to change the wallpapers, but then uninstalled it completely. Surprisingly, the wallpaper still keeps changing, possibly every 15 minutes (my guess, I have not measured). I cannot find any corresponding option under setting where I can stop it, or set another frequency. Where can I find the options?

Comment: Try ps -A to see what processes are happening. You may find what is making this.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have removed it entirely. Muzaffar has the right idea.

`ps -ax | grep desktopnova` - this will tell you if any running process contains 'desktopnova' and the number (known as the pid) of the process

`sudo kill -9 #####` - instead of the # marks, put the pid of the process here. this will kill the process (without exception, hence -9).

`sudo apt-get purge desktopnova desktopnova-module-gnome` - this should remove any leftover remnants.

---

You may need to reinstall and remove the package entirely using this method if it has not entirely uninstalled.

If you run into any problems, don't forget you can access other TTYs with CTRL-ALT-F6 and restart gdm.